# C function prototype in Bash source code with two names?

Tags: c, bash

```
static void close_pipes __P((int, int));
```

I don't get it, it seems like close_pipes would be the function name, but then there is this __P which looks more like a function because of the parens and params.  I am not a C programmer, what am I looking at here?

Comment: You're looking at a macro.

Comment: Basically you can ignore the `__P(` and `)`... and no one should write this any more as the other expansion has been obsolete for 29 years now.

Comment: `#if __STDC__ != 0` / `#define __P(x) x` / `#else` / `#define __P(x) /* Nothing */` / `#endif` — or words to that effect.  Note the double-parentheses; those are crucial.  It allows for compilers that do not support prototypes, but such compilers are vanishingly rare.  New code should not bother with the contortion.  Old code should be cleaned up to remove the notation — unless there's a definitive project requirement to continue support for antiquated (pre-standard, meaning pre-1990) compilers.